# Count number of capital letters in file Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of unique capital letter from a text file which contains text data. I have done with counting the capital letter from file but need your help in how to count unique capital letters.

This is what i have tried yet:

```
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    count = 0
    text = countletter.read()
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper():
            count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: You need to include more information. Does this code work? Does it not work? If not, exactly how does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of capital letters that already appeared. Using set is a feasible solution.

```
letters = set()
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    count = 0
    text = countletter.read()
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper():
            count += 1
            letters.add(character)
print(count)
```

Very compact solution:

```
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    count = sum(character.isupper() for character in set(countletter.read()))
    print(count)
```

Comment: Ehh you should use a set instead of `if not in list` as it is way faster and is actually the proper usage for this use case.

Comment: Better to use a set for this, instead of a list, since the only thing you're using it for is adding and membership tests. Both are O(1) on a set, but membership tests are O(n) on a list.

Answer (score 2):

solution using set

```
unique_capital_letters = set()
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    text = countletter.read()
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper():
            unique_capital_letters.add(character)

number_of_unique_occurrences = len(unique_capital_letters)
print(number_of_unique_occurrences)
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the capitals are unique like AS2 asked it will add the same letter multiple times if it occures more than once

Comment: Oops didn't look at the brackets properly. I do think it should print len(unique_capital_letters) though as he asked for the amount?

Comment: @Eric, you are right. I have submitted an edit for it

Comment: Note that `{}` creates a dictionary, not a set. Use `set()` to create an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the characters to a list. Then create a set out of it and take it length. This will give you the unique Capital Characters. Something like below:

```py
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    char_list = list()
    count = 0
    text = countletter.read()
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper():
            #append the capitals
            char_list.append(character)

#create a set and get its length
print(len(set(char_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to record all the capitals letter that have already appeared.

Something like

```
CapitalChar=''
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    count = 0
    text = countletter.read()
    for character in text:
        if character.isupper() and not in CapitalChar:
            CapitalChar=CapitalChar + character
            count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, just wanted to point out that you can use a `Counter` to make life much easier:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    unique = Counter(countletter.read())
    unique_capital_letters = {char: count for char, count in unique.items() if char.isupper()}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already some perfect answers posted here, but just for convenience here is a very compact way to achieve it with just regular python:

```
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
  count = sum(character.isupper() for character in set(countletter.read()))
```

A set guarantees every element is unique, and sum used like I did ads one to count each time the character is uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Eric's answer, but with the `map` function instead:

```
with open('demo.txt') as countletter:
    count = sum(map(str.isupper, set(countletter.read())))
```

Comment: this does look a little cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your goal. People are surely giving you a way based on the logic of your code. Here, I give you a new way to achieve your goal by using *list comprehensions* synthax.

```
with open('demo.txt') as f:
   text = f.read()
   count = len(set([character for character in text if character.isupper()]))

print(count)
```